# Each time I create superuser, Django saves the user but throws an error that user already exists even if it has never existed

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am fairly new to advanced Django and using Django 4.2 and PostGreSql 9.5 with PgAdmin4. I am trying to create a website, where users can sign in with email and password. I have created the models like so:

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='this designates if the user\' email is verified')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='this designates if the user is active')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='this designates if the user is staff or not')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='password of user')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='this designates if the user is superuser or not')
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Last login of user', auto_now_add=True)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Time user was created')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['id', 'email']
    

    objects = UserManager()
```

my user manager class is like this:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
   def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
       if not email:
           raise ValueError('Email must be provided')
       user = self.model(
           email = self.normalize_email(email), 
           **kwargs
       )
       user.set_password(password)
       user.save(using=self._db)
       return user 
   
   def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
       kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)
       kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
       kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', False)
       user = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           password=password,
           **kwargs
       ) 

       user.save()
       return self._create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
   
   def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
       kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)
       kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', True)
       kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
       user = self.model(
           email=self.normalize_email(email),
           password=password,
           **kwargs
       )

       user.save()
       return self._create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
```

I was told that if I want to authenticate email instead of username, I should create a custom backend. My custom backend looks like this:

**backends.py**

```
class CaseSensitiveModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username, password, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()

        if not username:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)

        try:
            case_insensitive_username_field = '{}__iexact'.format(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get(**{case_insensitive_username_field: username})
            success = user.check_password(password)
            if success:
                return user
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
           return None
        
        

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        return
```

Yet after creating migrations and migrating, when I try to create a superuser, it tells me that the superuser already exists, even if the database is a new one and nothing existed inside it, while still throwing this error:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "bloggers_users_email_key" DETAIL:  Key (email)=(twinklet123@gmail.com) already exists.`
**THIS ERROR COMES RIGHT AFTER THE USER HAS BEEN SAVED TO THE DATABASE ALREADY**

I have also tried to login to admin with the so-called saved user, yet it throws a case-sensitive error.

I am very confused, please can anyone help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i get it right the create_superuser returns a *_create_user* function call which tries to save another User object
with the same data

so regardless of the error the user should be there

did you add your backend via AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS to the settings.py?

Comment: Yes. What I did was to restart the project, and remove the authentication backends. I just used a baseusermanager class and that was it. It's working now